# Link custom tables to rolemanager

Tags: asp.net, .net, frameworks, roles

I'm working on a School project and I just started working on the presentation layer.
I want to use the rolemanager that asp.net provides to limit certain pages and elements to certain groups of users.
Now when making the database for everything I already took account for making  a table for my users which contains a role,username and password variable.
Now I'm trying to find a way to link these so that I can still use the role limiting functions

My project is in ASP.NET using .NET Framework

Greetings

Comment: Show us some of your code so we can help you

Comment: @ekstroem There is no code, just data